# in anaconda, pythonw.exe is not showing up inside my directory. what can i do?

Tags: python, anaconda

While trying to set up PyCharm with a Conda environment, I looked into my environment, but pythonw.exe is not showing up. I am on OS X

Answer (score 1):

`pythonw.exe` is Windows specific. Windows has a strict segregation between command line applications and non-command line applications; `pythonw.exe` is just Python declared as a non-command line application so a command prompt isn't created for scripts it runs (typically you don't want one for GUI applications).

On any other system, including OSX, plain `python` (or `python3`, as appropriate) handles both command line and non-command line applications.